# JLayeredPane draw picture

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw picture in JLayeredPane, with the following code, but all I see is a small picture in the last cell, maybe 5x5px. I don't know why. any suggestion? thank you.

```
    try {
        imgL0 = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/L0.png"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");
        System.exit(1);                
    }

    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imgL0);
    JLabel img = new JLabel();        
    img.setIcon(imageIcon);
    img.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize, boardSize);
    field = new JLayeredPane[boardSize][boardSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
            field[i][j] = new JLayeredPane();
            field[i][j].setSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
            field[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            field[i][j].add(img);
            field[i][j].repaint();
            field[i][j].revalidate();                
            boardPanel.add(field[i][j], JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to add a JLabel multiple times to different containers, and this is not allowed in Swing GUI's, since with Swing a component can be added only once, and if it is added to multiple containers, it only shows in the last one added. Instead consider creating a JPanel that holds a grid of JLabels, and add a single ImageIcon multiple times (this is allowed for ImageIcons) to the JLabels held by the grid.

Your code has other curiosities including trying to add multiple JLayeredPanes which is an extremely unusual requirement. Just what is it that you're trying to build here? I have to believe that there's a better way to do this, whatever it is.

Comment: I'm trying to create a game. So I need playing board with fields, on each field I need background, on that picture and player pawn. long story short I need layers, how can I achive this with jlabel? thanks

Comment: @user3463614: A background can be achieved with a grid of JPanels. I posit that you actually in fact **don't** need a JLayeredPane grid. If you described your problem in even greater detail, I'd be able to explain my suggestion in greater detail. And with regard to `"how can I achieve this with JLabel"` -- again, you can use a grid of JLabel and set its Icon. Alternatively if you need JPanels, then create a grid of drawing JPanels and pass your images there. Again, the more detail you can give us the more detail we can give you.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work. Now I have JPanel with gridview, in each cell I insert another JPanel and then JLabel with background, so I have sth like chessboard, the only problem is that I'm not able to draw more than one cell at the same time ... btw thank you, very much.